# With flask/jinja, what is a viable way to safely render a link inside a user generated block of text?

Tags: python, regex, security, flask, jinja2

Think twitter where you paste a link next to some plain text and when your tweet is rendered, that url is now a clickable link.

Do I:

- replace jinja's autoescape with my own by scanning the text for html tags and replacing them with the html entity code
- use a regular expression to detect a url contained in the text and replace it within an a href=

  - what would this expression look like to detect any # of .tld's, http/https, www/any subdomain?
- and render this all as ¦safe in the template?

Or is there a python/flask/jinja 'feature' that can better handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jinja has a filter built-in called [`urlize`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#urlize) that should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Sounds great! Does it say anywhere or do you know where I could find the sourcecode as to how it determines what is a url?

Comment: @chrickso - try https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/master/jinja2/utils.py#L263